# How do I include the access_token claims in the ProfileDataRequestContext?

Tags: c#, .net, oauth-2.0, identityserver3

This is a follow up question to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841927/how-do-i-include-claims-into-the-access-token-retrieved-from-the-authorize-endpo/37842521#37842521). My question is in regards to when I query the custom UserInfoEndpoint I expect the claims from my access token (which is sent as a bearer token in the request) to be part of the context `ProfileDataRequestContext`. The problem is they are not, specifically I am wanting the `ticket` claim to be in the context, however the context is empty(except for `sub` which as I understand is always present).

Please see my previous question in regards to the implementation as I dont want to repost everything here.

Thanks in advance...

Logs for reference...

```
2016-06-15 13:52:11.508 -05:00 [Information] Creating userinfo response
2016-06-15 13:52:11.513 -05:00 [Information] Scopes in access token: "app openid offline_access appaccess"
2016-06-15 13:52:11.514 -05:00 [Information] Requested claim types: "applicationDto sub"
2016-06-15 13:52:11.514 -05:00 [Debug] Getting ProfileDataAsync
2016-06-15 13:52:11.514 -05:00 [Debug] The claims in the context...
2016-06-15 13:52:11.514 -05:00 [Debug] Claims sub 783bf872-b864-4042-853d-04fbcb7a505a
2016-06-15 13:52:11.514 -05:00 [Debug] The requseted claims...
2016-06-15 13:52:11.514 -05:00 [Debug] Cliams applicationDto
2016-06-15 13:52:11.514 -05:00 [Debug] Cliams sub
2016-06-15 13:52:11.514 -05:00 [Debug] Finished ProfileDataAsync
2016-06-15 13:52:11.514 -05:00 [Information] Profile service returned to the following claim types: "sub"
2016-06-15 13:52:11.514 -05:00 [Information] End userinfo request
2016-06-15 13:52:11.516 -05:00 [Information] Returning userinfo response.
```

Update: 
After discussing the issue on [github](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2989), its been determined that this is not supported, it was suggested that I put the ticket in the id_token, however this still does not fix the problem.

Is there any way I can get the `ticket` claim as part of the context in the UserInfoEndpoint?

Logs after the update...

```
2016-06-16 12:23:08.023 -05:00 [Information] Creating userinfo response
2016-06-16 12:23:08.027 -05:00 [Information] Scopes in access token: "app openid offline_access appaccess"
2016-06-16 12:23:08.028 -05:00 [Information] Requested claim types: "applicationDto sub ticket"
2016-06-16 12:23:08.028 -05:00 [Debug] Getting ProfileDataAsync
2016-06-16 12:23:08.028 -05:00 [Debug] Claims in Claims in the context...
2016-06-16 12:23:08.028 -05:00 [Debug]     "sub : 783bf872-b864-4042-853d-04fbcb7a505a"     
2016-06-16 12:23:08.028 -05:00 [Debug] Claims in Requested Claims...
2016-06-16 12:23:08.028 -05:00 [Debug]     "applicationDto"     
2016-06-16 12:23:08.028 -05:00 [Debug]     "sub"     
2016-06-16 12:23:08.028 -05:00 [Debug]     "ticket"     
2016-06-16 12:23:08.028 -05:00 [Debug] Claims in Issued Claims...
2016-06-16 12:23:08.028 -05:00 [Debug]     "sub : 783bf872-b864-4042-853d-04fbcb7a505a"     
2016-06-16 12:23:08.028 -05:00 [Debug] Finished ProfileDataAsync
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That expectation is wrong - userinfo is an OpenID Connect concept and is an alternative way to get to the claims that would otherwise be in an identity token. Not an access token.

That said - in your `GetProfileDataAsync` method in your user service you can detect from the context if you are being called via the userinfo endpoint and can return any claims you like.